# A Kawasaki BX1 or BX2?

Tags: bmx

Trying to find if this is a BX1 or BX2 I can only find the serial number 0622 on the bottom? There is not a B1 or B2 Like I have seen to look for?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. You need to add a picture (or several) to your question (edit your question to add them), otherwise the question will be closed. Serial numbers are rarely helpful.  Pictures are always helpful.

Comment: I don't know anything about these bikes or if its worth hanging onto? I also found a 1967 Stingray also not sure what style of bike it is....

Comment: Both this bike and the Stingray are collectable. Check eBay for current ballpark values.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the bikes posted on the [bmxmuseum.com](https://bmxmuseum.com/) website I don't see a BX1 or a BX2.
[I do see a BX-100](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/kawasaki/38824)
[image]

[and a BX-200](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/kawasaki/30527)
[image]

If your bike looks like one of these two then you have a match.

Comment: Thank you! I actually just found it after I cleaned it up its a BX100 not sure what year or anything about it I got it from a barn.

Comment: @Christa From what I can tell BX100s where only made in 1975